# Bootstrap 3 navbar-toggle height

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I use two navbar-toggle button in navbar with my homepage.

But those button are different as using glyphicon icon.

Here is capture image.

Image Link : https://i.stack.imgur.com/mtqm7.jpg

See image, right-up side, two navbar-toggle button height are different each other.

How can I change two navbar-toggle button to same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

maybe u can override the padding of the button according to above preview image?

as using inspect element, the original default styling is

```
.navbar-toggle {
position: relative;
float: right;
padding: 9px 10px;
margin-top: 8px;
margin-right: 15px;
margin-bottom: 8px;
background-color: transparent;
background-image: none;
border: 1px solid transparent;
border-radius: 4px;
min-height: 33px;
}
```

then u maybe can create some css with higher priority for overriding default style

//inline style , !important as you like.

```
.navbar-toggle {
    padding-top:12px;  
    padding-bottom:12px;
}
```

For your reference,
use your browser dev tools to do live edit to meet your alignment requirements.